# Laravel/Envoy TaskContainer line 330 Probleme

Tags: php, laravel-envoy

I try for Laravel Envoy for deployment easily. But ! Despite my research, I can not find an answer.

When I try to put more than one line in a story or macro, it does not handle at all and sends me an error.

I have the impression that the TaskContainer does not manage space and takes all for a single Task. Hum... not just an impression.

**Code in Envoy.blade.php :**

```
...

@task('test_1')
    echo "test 1";
@endtask

@task('test_2')
    echo "test 2";
@endtask

@story('test')
    test_1
    test_2
@endstory
```

**Result :**

```
$ envoy run test

In TaskContainer.php line 330:

  Task "test_1
      test_2" is not defined.


run [--continue] [--pretend] [--path PATH] [--conf CONF] [--] <task>
```

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created pull request to fix it
https://github.com/laravel/envoy/pull/168

If you don't want clone laravel/envoy repository and change in `src/TaskContainer.php`

```php
$macro = explode(PHP_EOL, $this->trimSpaces(trim(ob_get_clean())));
```

to:

```php
$macro = preg_split('/\n|\r\n?/', $this->trimSpaces(trim(ob_get_clean())));
```

Then you can run envoy like `php <envoy_dir>\bin\envoy run <task>`